# Jquery parse XML problem

Tags: jquery, xml, parsing

I have an XML structure where some elements are repeated inside the parent element, and i want to pick the first of the repeated element, how can i achieve that.
$(doc).find('myElement').text() returns the concat value of both the elements, can i have only the first value.

Appreciate the help in advance.

Vaibhav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried: $(doc).find('myElement').first().text()
?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(doc).find('myElement').eq(0).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use XPath to retrive the information . Can you post the XML file ?